# how to override the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.IsReadOnly();

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I want to override the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.IsReadOnly();`

because of which i get the `Connectionstring` is `Readonly`. when I tried to edit that on Run time

```
ConnectionStringSettings connectionStringSettingInstance = 
                            new ConnectionStringSettings(connectionName,
                                                         ConnectionStringBuilded,
                                                         ConnectionProvider);
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Add(connectionStringSettingInstance);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it all mixed up.

A readonly collection will remain readonly no matter what you attempt. 
It's not a switch, it is a definition.

Furthermore, that collection comes from the app.config, and you cannot add dynamically to that collection because it is physical: everything that appears in the ConfigurationManager static class at runtime is actually physically written in the app.config

That's the theory, in practice however, [you can cheat this by using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900350/adding-connectionstring-at-runtime-app-config-and-display-without-reloading-appl).

So, all hope is not lost. But when you come to a point where you try to cheat the framework into doing something it was not meant to do, it is time to rethink your design.

Comment: ...or you do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8796252/58961), which doesn't involve reflection.